Assigning a footprint to LED symbol in Altium Designer
I'm trying to assign an LED footprint to an LED symbol but I don't know how to do it. I don't even know if this is what you would do if you wanted to make a PCB LED array but hopefully I'm on the right track. How would this be done and what am I missing based off these screenshots?


I'm guessing that this symbol needs to be in the schematic library instead...

I would suggest going through the Altium basic training from the documentation. That will teach you what you need to know.  https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/tutorial-complete-design-walkthrough

You can assign several information to a schematic symbol, one of them is footprint, consider the following resistor:

When you left-click on it, on the right side, you should be able to see the properties window:

Then, we you press add, you can see footprint:

Finally, select the related directory for your footprint it should be fine.
